# Convert one column into multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I simply want to take data from Column A and put it into Column B, Row 1; Column C, row 1 and Column D, row 1.

I want to put it into groups of three from top to bottom.

For example:

```
Column A
1
2
3
4
5
1
1
2
3
```

I want it to look like this

```
1 2 3
4 5 1 
1 2 3
```

and keep on going.

Comment: do you want formula? vba?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a formula to achieve this.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROW($A1)-1)*3+COLUMN(A1),1))
```

Enter the formula above into a blank cell. Copy it two cells to the right, then down until you start to get zeros (delete these).

In this formula, **A1** points to the first item in the column you want to re-arrange. To change the number of columns, modify `3` in the formula into something else.

Comment: If you need to do this for a group not starting at A1, you need to get a little more detailed with the offsets, like this (example has column starting at B3): `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROW($B3)-ROW($B$3)+1)*3+COLUMN(B3)-COLUMN($B3),COLUMN($B3)))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in VBA (assuming that the data are in column `A`):

```
Option Explicit

Sub movetocolumns()
Dim i As Integer, iRow As Integer
Dim arrSource As Variant

'Set the first row
iRow = 1

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'get the data into an array from the first column
    arrSource = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    'parse every value of the array and add the data to the next column
    For i = 1 To (UBound(arrSource) - UBound(arrSource) Mod 3) Step 3
        .Cells(iRow, 2) = arrSource(i, 1)
        .Cells(iRow, 3) = arrSource(i + 1, 1)
        .Cells(iRow, 4) = arrSource(i + 2, 1)
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next i
    'add the remaining values
    Select Case UBound(arrSource) Mod 3
        Case 1  'one item to add
            .Cells(iRow, 2) = arrSource(i, 1)
        Case 2  'still two items to add
            .Cells(iRow, 2) = arrSource(i, 1)
            .Cells(iRow, 3) = arrSource(i + 1, 1)
        Case Else   'nothing to add
    End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to convert it to multiple columns first, then select the column values and press Ctrl + C to copy them, then select a cell and right click to select Paste Special > Transpose.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly pretty, but I was able to do it with 3 helper columns and a pivot table, as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In further extension to Ellesa's and Joshua's solution the following will paste from and to an arbitrary place in the sheet. The single column starting at `$G$93` is transformed into rows with 10 entries each starting at `$M$93`:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($G$93)+(ROW($M93)-ROW($M$93))*10+(COLUMN(M93)-COLUMN($M$93)),COLUMN($G$93)))
```